# split the title and count the splited words how many times present in repective paragraph in c#.net

Tags: c#, arrays, string, for-loop, c#-4.0

I got a requirement like this. 
two things available in a page i.e. 
**Post title and
post content paragraph.**
1st the post title sentence is split into words than count the words how many times present in the respective post content paragraph. what is the appropriate logic should in C#.net?

Comment: Your tags answer your `what is the appropriate logic` question. Have you tried something? Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

For Splitting text use:

```
         string[] words = postTitle.Split(' ');
```

Then use below method to find each word count inside post content:

```
public static int CountWords(string s)
{
    MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(s, @"[\S]+");
    return collection.Count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a try with his:

```
string postTitle = "This is Title";
string postContent = "This will be the content corresponds to the above title, this will be updated later";
string[] contentWords = postContent.Split(' ');
var wordsNcount = String.Join("\n", postTitle.Split(' ').Select(x => x + " : " + contentWords.Count(y => y == x).ToString()));
```

This will be case sensitive comparison, you can refer the [Live example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rMTEIg), in which I have included case insensitive comparison as well.